# SWIFT - UIDatePicker - start and end date selection but can't figure out how to call both dates into two different text boxes

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a static cells in a tableview controller where I am asking the user to put in a start and end date into two separate text fields. I am using `UIDatePicker`, when the text box is pushed the date picker controller pops up.

I can get the datepicker called up for both boxes but can only get the date to display in the first box. My coding is below. I know I am only coding the first box to display and thought if I just used the same coding the second box would display but I get an error. How do I change my code such that `handleDatePicker` will do the start and end dates?

```
@IBAction func startDate(sender: UITextField) {
    var startDatePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    startDatePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = startDatePickerView
    startDatePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    startDateTextLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}

@IBAction func endDate(sender: UITextField) {
    var endDatePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    endDatePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = endDatePickerView
    endDatePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something similar to this:

```
var timeSelected: UITextField!

@IBAction func pickUpDate(sender: UITextField) {

    var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    sender.inputView = datePickerView

    timeSelected = sender
    ***CODE***

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: "handleDatePicker:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
}
```

So the handleDatePicker function:

```
func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    timeSelected.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

As you can see, the timeSelected will change if you are clicking in the first UITextField or in the second one, so timeSelected.text will replace the value in the correct one. You only need one pickUpDate function for both textFields (from your Storyboard just CTRL + Mouse Pointer from the textField to the @IBAction block)

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: after hours of trying to program case/switch using tags from UITextFields i still couldnt get the date placed into the UITextField... found this post and whipped it into my project. Wahhhlahh... works like a charm. Thanks for this. i have about 8 different date pickers on a form in my application. This works brilliantly from any textfield.